How to use Angular and Neutralinojs
I try to build a desktop application using Angular and Neutralinojs.
According to https://neutralino.js.org/docs/getting-started/using-frontend-libraries/ I try to use the @neutralinojs/lib and just including the __neutralino_globals.js file in my index.html.
In the main.ts I have the following code:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import * as neutralinojs from "@neutralinojs/lib";

declare global {
  const NL_MODE: String;
}

if (typeof NL_MODE !== 'undefined' && NL_MODE == "window") {
  Neutralino.init();
  Neutralino.events.on("windowClose", () => {
    Neutralino.app.exit();
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)
  ]
});

Unfortunately I get the following error in my Neutralino application:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Neutralino is not defined
    at 103 (main.472a06f9fbfbf5cf.js:1:555101)
    at a (runtime.7774ff81d752b5d3.js:1:127)
    at main.472a06f9fbfbf5cf.js:1:555301
    at l (runtime.7774ff81d752b5d3.js:1:683)
    at main.472a06f9fbfbf5cf.js:1:72 

As soon as I add <script src="assets/neutralino.js"></script> the script it works as expected.
Is there the documentation wrong or did I mixed up several different styles?
Versions:

neu CLI: v11.0.1
Neutralinojs binaries: v5.1.0
Neutralinojs client: v5.1.0
Angular 16.2.0

